# Google apps scripting regular expression

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I have a google apps script that I've written, and have it very close to working the way I would like it too.

Currently it will grab the top 100 emails in an inbox, do some filtering on them, scrape some fields using regular expressions and then create an email to send out with the scraped and formatted content.

This type of emails I'm scrapping are standardized for the most part. The bodies of the emails have pre defined fields like:

Subject:
Date:
Reply Date:
Requirements:
Contract Number:

So the regular expression searches for the hard coded values like "Subject:" and then captures everything after the colon until it hits a new line character. It does so with this statement:

content.match(/Subject :(.*)/)

It will match anything after the colon until it hits a new line character. This works for almost all of the fields I need to scrape. One however, is a bit more trouble. One of them, the last one I need to scrape (not shown above) will span multiple lines. There's no way to predict how long it will be, but instead I have another predefined piece of text I can use to determine where to stop capturing.

So for example, one field can span any number of lines and then there will be a message similar to ****end of input**** in the message body. I want to capture anything starting from my match clause, say for example... "subject:" and stop when it hits the predefined phrase "****end of input****"

How can I write the match clause regular expression to do so?

I've done a lot of research, but nothing fruitful. Regular expressions are not something I'm very good at.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Something like [`/Subject :\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\*+end of input\*+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/mR7aI1/1)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Why not use `s` flag here to match text spanning multiple lines ?

Comment: @noob: JavaScript RegExp does not support singleline / DOTALL mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use lazy matching of any characters including a newline with `[\s\S]*?` restricted with a lookahead that will check if we reached the `****end of input****` substring:

```
/Subject :\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\*{4}end of input\*{4})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR7aI1/3)

However, for longer texts, I'd rather use an unrolled version of the same regex:

```
/Subject :\s*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*{3}end of input\*{4})[^*]*)*)/
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/mR7aI1/2)